# Generate script of newly added data in all tables of database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a script which give a insert statements of all tables or only one can also work(I will make multiple for each table) which are newly added in the table after particular time period.

For example insert script for the data added after 11:40 P.M.

Comment: Do all your table have created_date columns?

Comment: No. Thats why i am asking .... is it possible or not ??

Comment: Why for, do you want to send them to another db use replication or mirroring, do you want to track them use Change Data Capture???

Comment: Oh man ... mine problem is diffrent ... i have to generate script of inserted data after perticular time period ... i would add new column of created date but it will make my existing project like hell,... stop downvoting and anser me please

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure how you gonna do that with your current situation , but you can in the future use trigger on DML or add column as O_DATE which contain time-stamp of insert time,hope that will help you..